# Graduation Robes - What accolades does this guy have?

Tags: academic-life, graduation, outward-appearance, academic-dress

[image]

I am currently at my brother's graduation ceremony at Adelaide University, and in the Professor's/Post-grad seating area, sits a man fully in green. What does this special gown mean?

(Apologies for the awful picture)[image]

Comment: It is difficult to tell from the picture. At graduation ceremonies I've been to the color of professors robes have referenced the universities they attended, not any special accolades.

Comment: I got another photo! He's the only one in an unusual colour so I don't think it's to do with that

Comment: Wait for the ceremony to get over. Either you will know it by then or probably, you could approach him and ask gently.

Comment: Most schools, at least in the US, have black robes. See this list https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_regalia_in_the_United_States and not everyone buys their schools robes since they cost 1000 USD so it is not surprising that he is the only one with unique colors.

Comment: I love the cap.

Comment: The type of cap may indicate the type of doctoral degree.  IIRC that looks vaguely like a Divinity School  cap.

Comment: Not all of the other robes are black. The robe of the person four behind him in the procession appears to be navy blue.

Comment: Wizard who can charm plants?

Comment: The kelly green typically represents some field of medicine.

Comment: I wonder if he is wearing CSU regalia https://www.gowningstreet.com.au/uni/csu/bachelor-of-education ?

Comment: Christmas dwarf?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I asked this question on the [Facebook 'Academical Dress' group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/991333104293186/permalink/1463696113723547/), where Patrick Cook was able to find out who the figure in green is:

> It is Polish. The gentleman in question if Prof. Maciej Henneberg. His qualifications are listed as MSc, PhD and DSc (Dr habil), all from A Mickiewicz University, Poznan. So I'm guessing the gown is either the PhD or the DSc.
>   [http://www.chinadaily.com.cn/.../03/content_5448095.htm](http://www.chinadaily.com.cn/world/2007-08/03/content_5448095.htm?fref=gc&dti=991333104293186)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great digging work!

Comment: Credit to Patrick Cook (who is not me)!

Answer (score 33):

It is conventional in many places for faculty who participate in a graduation ceremony to wear the regalia from the university where they got their degree. Some universities have more... elaborate regalia than others.(See e.g. [Etiquette of wearing the wrong academic robes at graduation as a lecturer in the UK](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/48143/etiquette-of-wearing-the-wrong-academic-robes-at-graduation-as-a-lecturer-in-the), especially [this comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/48143/etiquette-of-wearing-the-wrong-academic-robes-at-graduation-as-a-lecturer-in-the#comment111376_48143). And [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/44330/11365).)

Others sitting on stage in your photos appear to be wearing the [Adelaide University regalia](http://www.gowntown.com.au/gowns/adelaide/doctor-phd) - maybe that's where they did their doctorate (or they did it at a university that uses the same regalia), or maybe they don't have the regalia from their alma mater and just wear this one.

Comment: +1 ... the university where that guy got his doctoral degree had green robes.  Here in the US most doctoral robes are black.  But not all.  I would wear my crimson robes from Harvard, for example.

Comment: I think the first class at Harvard must be on how to work the fact that one has gone to Harvard into every conversation...

Comment: @BradWerth I also went to Harvard.  It cost $5.00 on the red line.  I did not study there, but it was worth it to be able to interject into every conversation "I went to Harvard."  It was a valuable inflection point that led me to my 8 year residency (outside) the White House.  I do not wear a Harvard robe.  My Harvard tee-shirt does the job of informing people about my association with Harvard University.