# Which university uses or used this academic regalia?

Tags: university, academic-dress

Given information about academic regalia such as colour and style of graduation robes, how can I determine the university that used that regalia?
I have the photo below, and would like to find out what university this graduation was for.

[image]

Comment: @aeismail I get this is somehow off-topic (let me get back to it in a moment). But certainly this is not a shopping question: it doesn't ask for recommendations for choosing a uni, but asks for help finding one's relative based on a photo from a graduation ceremony. And while this is certainly not within the scope of this site, it makes sense that the OP thought it would be best to ask people involved in universities around the world. I'd recommend to reopen the question for a few days, and close/delete it afterwards. Why not use the power of internet to help someone?No need to be so stringent

Comment: Questions that are only of assistance to a single individual that will not be of benefit to future visitors of the site are considered off-topic on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @corey979 The issue has to do with curation. Once the question is done, it will be of little value to future users of the site. This runs against the SE philosophy. (If anybody knows the answer, they’re free to leave a comment.)

Comment: @aeismail That's why I said it can be closed/deleted after a few days. My point in it is that an _on hold_ question may attract less attention - people that might help, won't even look at it. And using the capabilities of the community here to help one individual is better than not helping anyone, don't you agree? Yes, this question is off-topic, but sticking to the manual seems like a terrible waste of resources that the internet provides...

Comment: @corey979 You can also nominate the question to be reopened. If the argument is good enough it should rally people to sponsor it for reopening as a first step.

Comment: Perhaps the question could be rephrased as "How can you find out which university used or uses a particular graduation robe, colours, etc.?" to which one possible answer might be "contact a company that provides academic robes for a particular country (or in the U.S., state), they may know." This information might be of interest to people doing genealogy or historical research.

Comment: Jack, I reworded your question to make it more general. If that's not acceptable, you can change it back. I don't know if this will be sufficient to get it reopened.

Comment: hmm, this is University of southern california

Comment: I would vote to reopen this question if it included a textual description of these academic regalia --- so there is at least a chance that someone ends up here with a Google search and finds it helpful.

Comment: @aeismail this was considered on topic https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/95944/graduation-robes-what-accolades-does-this-guy-have but green is much less common.

Comment: Okay. I guess I’ve been overruled. But i still think it sets a bad precedent.